# How do you bundle multiple AMD modules in a single file?

Tags: amd, javascript

AMD seems to be the best practice to load javascript modules as-needed.

This should work great on large web-apps where users only use a fraction of the available functionality.

I've read about the optimizer, which concatenates all required modules into a single file, and I've read about no optimization, i.e. loading each module with a async request.

Both don't seem to fit this use-case: loading every module with a request might quickly result in a large number of request, whereas optimizing forces you to download **all** the code.

Is there a way to bundle multiple modules into a single file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RequireJS supports this use-case with their optimization tool.

With the proper configuration in build.js, it can be configured to bundle multiple modules in multiple files.

Their mapping can be defined in [build.js](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage/blob/master/tools/build.js) as shown in this [example project](https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage)

Answer (score 9):

Yes.
Generally dividing application to so many files and loading them with AMD is **only good for development**. It helps to keep the code clean and understandable; it's quite logical that each module contains views, models, controllers and each of them is a separate file.

Yet that **large number of request doesn't make sense in production**. Thus you should use optimizer to compile and minimize files into one (or a few) to improve performance and user experience.

If you're using RequireJS please refer to http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject — it explains how to use `r.js` tool provided by RequireJS.

For example if my application was consisting of public area, administration and a very complex sign up form each build up with hundreds views/models/controllers **I'd probably compile my code into just 4 files**: common, public, admin, sign_up. Then appropriate file would be asynchronously loaded when user entered specific zone.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts, but this not exactly the answer to my question: Can RequireJS resolve build those 4 different files, and resolve the module-to-filename in the browser?

I understand I could use several buildfiles to manually create 4 optimizes files with a bunch of modules. That leaves me with the clientside - how does it know to load the correct file?

Comment: Yes, it's explained on the page I linked to. Did you read it markmarijnissen? § 9 and § 10: http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject